# How do you create a conditional statement that selects multiple items in a column in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, mysql-workbench

I am a complete novice and I am trying to create a code where it will give me the participant_id's of people who have tracked both question_id = '1' and question = '10' and counts the result.

```
SELECT participant_id, created_on, question_id, question_label
FROM Data.tracking
Where 
    (question_id = '1' AND question_label = 'Where is the pain?' ) OR 
    (question_id = '10' AND question_label = 'What did you do to self-manage?') 
Group By participant_id
Having Count(distinct question_id)=2
```

Comment: What went wrong when you executed your attempt? What did you try next?

Comment: It gave an error saying this:  Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column data.tracking.created_on' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. From the question statement "**it will give me the participant_id's of people**" I have assumed that the column required in the output is the `participant_id` only. In case other columns are also required, please confirm we can modify the query or you can try yourself, this will help you to develop your skills.

```
SELECT a.participant_id 
from
(
SELECT participant_id , 
count(case when question_id = '1' AND question_label = 'Where is the pain?' then question_id end) ques_1_cnt,
count(case when question_id = '10' AND question_label = 'What did you do to self-manage?' then question_id end) ques_2_cnt
FROM Data.tracking
Where 
    (question_id = '1' AND question_label = 'Where is the pain?' ) OR 
    (question_id = '10' AND question_label = 'What did you do to self-manage?') 
Group By participant_id
) a
where a.ques_1_cnt > 0 and a.ques_2_cnt > 0;
```

Comment: It said that every derived table must have its own alias, what does this mean?

Comment: It just requires an alias for the subquery. I have updated the query. You can test now.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table DDL, this my best guess:

```
SELECT t.participant_id, t.created_on, t.question_id, t.question_label
FROM (
SELECT participant_id
FROM Data.tracking
Where 
    (question_id = '1' AND question_label = 'Where is the pain?' ) OR 
    (question_id = '10' AND question_label = 'What did you do to self-manage?') 
Group By participant_id
Having Count(distinct question_id)=2) s
INNER JOIN Data.tracking t
ON t.participant_id=s.participant_id
Where 
    (t.question_id = '1' AND t.question_label = 'Where is the pain?' ) OR 
    (t.question_id = '10' AND t.question_label = 'What did you do to self-manage?')
```

Comment: It said that there is an error in SQL syntax, is it because I am using workbench?